# Locking and unlocking screen in redhat

Tags: linux, redhat

Guys please I want to lock and unlock the screen from text mode where there is no GUI 
any help is appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `vlock` or if your system has `GNU-screen`, you can lock it up using `ctrl x` ([more screen cmds](http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference))

Using `screen` you can keep your background processes running which you can attach to later using the cmds mentioned in the link.

Comment: It gives me bash:lock: command not found

Comment: You might need to install it `yum install vlock` else use `GNU screen`

Comment: It gives me bash:GNU: command not found and when writing yum install clock it gives me red Hat network is not listed

Comment: No, the name of the binary is just `screen`, just run `screen`. And for the commands look into the link in my answer.

Comment: It gives me bash:screen: command not found

Answer (score 0):

Under text console you can try:

```
vlock -a
```

Comment: It gives me bash:lock: command not found

Comment: It is program from vlock rpm package. Maybe you have to install it?

Comment: It gives me red Hat is not listed